# Redirect url without .html type to html page

Tags: asp.net, windows, redirect, hosting

I have a godaddy (windows) hosting account and I want to redirect:

`www.example.com/folder/some` to `www.example.com/folder/some.html`

I tried adding this Web.config file, but cannot find what rule to add for redirecting the html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Add www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^[^.]*dav.*" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: I actually have a windows hosting account, so I have to change the Web.config file or something like that.  But thanks to you I started to figure it out!